# Hyperlink Columns = Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have many pdfs and an excel sheet in one folder. The naming sequence is consistent.

Sheet will be named Apple.
Pdfs will be named Apple_1, Apple_2

I want an excel macro to work
Get the active sheet name.
Hyperlink the cells in G column.
When I click on text in cell 1, it should open Apple_1.pdf
When I click on cell 2, it should open Apple_2.pdf.
This should continue until text filled cells in that column.

I have a Word macro for the same, but I don't know how to make it work in excel. Below is the word macro.

```
Sub macro3()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim coll As Column
Dim path As String
Dim pdf As String
Dim path1 As String
pdfname = ActiveDocument.Name
pdfname = Left(pdfname, Len(pdfname) - 4)
pdfname = Replace(pdfname, " ", "_")
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Set coll = tbl.Columns(7)
Set colpdf = tbl.Columns(7)
i = 0
For Each c In coll.Cells
If (i <> 0 And InStr(c, ".pdf") > 0) Then
path1 = pdfname & "_" & i & ".pdf"
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c.Range, Address:=path1
End If
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the directory path to the documents when setting path1. When you click the hyperlink to open its looking in a directory for "Apple1.pdf" which isn't a valid file path. You just need to add the directory path to the start of the path should look like "C:\MyPath\Apple1.pdf". 
Your code:

```
pdfname = ActiveDocument.Name
pdfname = Left(pdfname, Len(pdfname) - 4)
pdfname = Replace(pdfname, " ", "_")
path1 = pdfname & "_" & i & ".pdf"
```

Solution1: Assuming the documents are in the same folder as activedocument.

```
Dim MyPath as string
MyPath = ActiveDocument.Path
path1 = MyPath & "\" & pdfname & "_" & i & ".pdf"
```

Solution2: Files are in another location you can add another string address.

```
Dim MyPath as string
MyPath = "C:\MyOtherLocation"
path1 = MyPath & "\" & pdfname & "_" & i & ".pdf"
```